# Trying to manipulate state array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I need to write two functions, one for updating the shopping cart with new products (reserves) and another one to remove products from the cart.
I have many product suppliers, so I want to divide my "cart" array into sections like this:

```js
{
  "supplier1": ["product0": {props}, "product1": {props}, "productN": {props}],
  "supplier2": ["product0": {props}, "product1": {props}, "productN": {props}],
  "supplierN": ["product0": {props}, "product1": {props}, "productN": {props}],
}
```

I can succesfully add suppliers to my state array and also pushing product to supplier's arrays.
When i use

```js
setCart(cart)
```

cart array is updating but this is still old array, so React won't rerender my component

And in this case

```js
setCart([...cart])
```

cart array just becomes empty
So here is code of adding new products

```js
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
const addToCart = useCallback((options) => {
  //options.cart_section and options.reserve
  if(typeof cart[options.cart_section] === 'undefined'){
    cart[options.cart_section] = []
  }
  cart[options.cart_section].push(options.reserve)
  setCart([...cart])
}, [])
```

and code of removing products form cart

```js
const removeFromCart = useCallback((options) => {
  let index = cart[options.cart_section].indexOf(options.reserve) - 1
  cart[options.cart_section].splice(index,1)
  setCart([...cart])
})
```

It removes specified product but React doesn't rerender the component (same as in function below)
Sorry for my English and thanks for the help

Comment: You cannot mutate state directly. So you cannot be pushing/splicing the `cart` state. You have to use `setCart(changes required, ...cart)`

Comment: maybe try this:
```js
setCart(prev => prev[options.cart_section].push(options.reserve))
```
and 
```js
setCart(prev => prev[options.cart_section].splice(index,1))
```

Comment: @RaghuramSadineni unfortunately, `push()` returns length of array, so i get length in cart and `splice` removed supplier object, not product. I think i need somehow set another array that will equals to cart but has another reference, but i dont know the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Fist point. You can not assign key value like you did to array. but
  you can push objects as items of array. each object considered as a
  unique supplier. So your array should be like this:

```js
[
  {
    supplierName: 'supplie name 1',
    products: [
     {name: 'product name 1'}, 
     {name: 'product name 2'}
    ]
  },
  {
    supplierName: 'supplie name 2',
    products: [
     {name: 'product name 1'}, 
    {name: 'product name 2'}]
  }
]
```

- Second point. **never mutate state itself**. **you are mutating cart by pushing some thing inside of it. This way react will not rerender your component as you are not updating your state via setState**. you have to create a variable in your function from your state this way:

```
  let tempCart = cart.map(object => ({...object}))
```

after that you can push new supplier or product and at the end you should update your state via setCart. this way:

```
  setCart(tempCart)
```

this way you are updating your state via setState and react will treat this action as (need DOM to update) then your component will get rerender

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in my cart structure